How would time dilate for pioneers travelling to Alpha Centauri Cb?
Re: Relative Velocity Time Dilation:
Pioneers have travelled 4.2 light years to Alpha Centauri Cb in 9 months. Handwavium tech can transport mass in this timeframe. Upon their arrival to Cb, they are 9 months older, but how much time has passed on Earth?
Can you math-heads give me a rough idea of what this calculation would be?

There seems to be two questions. Can you edit out one, then ask it in its own thread. (The 3 weeks "massless transmission" would seem to be up to you anyhow as it breaks the speed of light and thus known physics too, but why wouldn't it be the same both-ways?)

if this is within real physics, the first one is a straight up time dilation calculation. the second one is not how physics works. if it's a fictional ftl tech, then you decide the rules.

Ty @Escapeddentalpatient. - "Mass Transportation" also breaks the speed of light, but given my lack of physics knowledge I haven't the slightest idea how to go about even loosely applied basic laws to influence the theory of this.

@Escapeddentalpatient. I wonder, am I understanding this correctly that it would be a dilation/difference between what the "data" experienced in time passage, versus the static observers of the sender or the recipient? And seeing how the "data" doesn't age, then it doesn't really matter what the dilation is?

So you want to know what fraction of light speed you would have to be traveling at to take 9 months (ship time allowing for time dilation) to travel 4.2 light years and from that how long that would take from the perspective of someone on earth if they could magically know when the ship arrives? .. if you do a search you should be able to find multiple calculators that will do that for you.

Regarding the faster-than light information transmission: That's a matter for the next question, but, no-one can answer that except you - since it breaks known physics. You're making the rules up about how it works. We can certainly help you figure out consistent rules, but you'd need to specify them in the first place.

@reiterwriter , space travel (in scifi or real life) is about acceleration issues and problems - not velocity.  Velocity is of no concern.

If the crew are 9 months older on arrival then the travel time isn't nine months, it's the time it takes the ship to experience nine months of relative, dilated, time, so is the travel time 9 months absolute or 9 months ship time?

A little bit more than 4.2 years. For any large time dilation factor, the astronauts spend most of the journey very close to the speed of light in the Earth frame, so you don't need to do a hard calculation unless you care about getting several decimal places of accuracy. Just use the amount of time it takes for light to get there, add a few percent, and mention that the course isn't a perfectly straight line to assuage any especially pedantic readers.
However, it can't be done the way you want with any technology permitted by real science if we further constrain the problem to keep regular humans alive during the trip. If you want squishy humans onboard to stay to stay alive, there are maximum acceleration limits, and you're way past them.
For ship time $t'_\text{max}$, ship observer measuring constant acceleration $a$, earth time $t_\text{max}$, with a flip halfway to the target point so you leave Earth at 0 and arrive at the target point at 0, speed of light $c$, total distance $X$
$t'_\text{max} = 2\frac{c}{a} \sinh^{-1}(\frac{a}{ct_\text{max}}) = 2\frac{c}{a} \sinh^{-1}(\frac{a}{c} \sqrt{\frac{(0.5Χ)^2}{c^2} + \frac{Χ}{a}})$
(the 2 is for the flip, we're covering one distance twice in a row)
The total distance measured by an observer on Earth (or Alpha Centauri) from Earth to the target point is related to time by the ship's velocity as measured by Earth and Earth's ordinary time, but the coordinate acceleration measured by Earth is not constant.
Plugging in a few test values I see that to get $t'_\text{max} = .75 yr$ with $X = 4.2 LY$ we need $a \approx 14g$, which will kill everyone onboard within a few minutes.
Referencing this article by Philip Gibbs.
Try deciding how big of an acceleration you want your futuristic medical tech to be able to help the astronauts survive, then plugging in $a$ and $X$ to get the ship time at arrival.

With suitable equipment available on Earth right now, humans can easily sustain 14g, I answered a question on max acceleration here a while ago: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/247019/maximum-acceleration-of-minimally-modified-humans-in-acceleration-fluid/247049#247049

@quarague - I fear the paper in the linked answer (by you! :) ) is bullshit, sorry.  (Just BTW you have "emerge" there, did you mean "submerge", "immerse" ?)  If you put someone in a tank of water, and then accelerate the vehicle at any g - then within seconds, the human will be squished against the floor or wall of the tank.  Being crushed by the floor or wall of the tank is no different at all than being crushed by any other surface of the spaceship, you'd be dead. (Even if you can breathe ok per the ESA :) )

@Fattie Well, the ESA (and the physics stack exchange also linked in my answer) disagrees with you. You will not be squished against the tank wall, this does work.

@Fattie If the fluid has the same density as the person, there will be no buoyant force at any acceleration, although there will be internal forces in the human because of the human's variable density (especially in the sinuses and lungs, since the difference in density between air and body is much bigger than the difference between fat and bone).

You can do this experiment. Make some thin simple syrup by adding a heap of sugar to scalding hot water. Get a clear jug and fill it most of the way with lukewarm water. Put a grape in the jug. Add syrup until the grape begins to float. Fill the bottle the rest of the way up with water until it starts to spill, then lid the bottle. Hold the jug up so that you can observe the motion of the grape, then violently swing it back and forth as hard as you can.

@gs hmm, I said "If you put someone in a tank of water".  Regarding using a perfectly matching density to the (average) density of the particular human, humans are far too irregular a mechanical body. (Just to begin with, your brain would instantly be squished within your skull.) To make perhaps a poor analogy, you can take a ball and bounce it off a wall and it survives; that does not prove that you can bounce a human off a wall. Another way to look at it, my guess is that the actual bottle/grape experiment - after a sustained 10g or 20g, the grape would be demolished by it's internal densi

ty irregularities, I'm afraid to say for the grape!

The trouble comes when you've body tissues of different density (muscle being denser than fat, bone denser still.). The brain is the delicate part, lipoproteins are midway between the densities of muscle and bone. Not sure what the limits are, I bet there's not widely publicized studies involving primates because of public outcry. Ask the Russians what experiments they did during the space-race. There might at least be some estimates of human limits in fluids.

@Fattie If you had perfectly matching densities you would not notice arbitrarily high densities. Now humans don't have perfectly homogenous densities but their density is approximately that of water, so it partially works, much better than humans in air. The ESA made experients to figure out how well it works and their result was humans in water with air breathing can sustain up to 24g.

@Escapeddentalpatient. , yes, precisely.  Quite simply, we're now talking engineering, not just abstract physics

@quarague (1) "if you had perfectly matching densities you would not notice arbitrarily high densities" sorry, that may have been directed to someone else or? (Matching density is matching density, it doesn't matter the value, "equals means equal".) (2) "humans don't have perfectly homogenous densities", the clearer way to express that is "Humans have extremely not homogenous density!"  :)  As I say, your brain would instantly be destroyed (this is the entire, total reason that you can get smacked in the gut with little ill effect, but smacking someone in the head eg. kills them), and I woul

d guess that for example your arm bones would rip through the flesh in your arms, etc., male astronauts testes would be mushed instantly, etc.  (4) "ESA - humans in water with air breathing can sustain up to 24g" I really think either (a) it's bullshit from the ESA or (b)( the devil is in the details, it may have been momentary, and/or with unusual slow (or fast IDK) onset etc.  Just BTW as far as I know there is no existing (human) centrifuge that can apply 24g for an length of time (ie more than a fraction of a second), that would be mindbogglingly difficult engineering. (It's extremely hard

to apply 20, 30g even to small lab samples.)  I really appreciate your report from the ESA and I will definitely look in to it but ATM my guess is something is unclearly stated in their report. (For example, they might be focussing only on the lung/breathing aspect (ie "of course your head would be crushed, but your brewathing will be fine!" heh!  :) :) )  thanks and cheers

Ty @gs, you've raised some spirited discussion =) I recognize that my question is asking for a physics answer to a physics-breaking question. Your response and others suggest that Earth would still experience light years—but if it only takes my travellers 9 months, wouldn't that make them "time travellers" too? Say my travellers leave in 2024, arrive at the beginning of 2025 to Alpha Centauri. Earth won't "experience" their arrival for another 4.2 light years... so wouldn't any travellers' messages sent to Earth be received before their arrival?

@reiterwriter No. The astronauts and the Earthlings disagree about the amount of time that has passed, the distance traversed, who was moving and who was stationary (wherever you go, there you are, so the astronauts never moved, the whole universe boosted into a new frame instead!), whose clocks were time dilated and when, and whose lengths were contracted and when. But they agree that ~4.3 years passed on Earth and Alpha Centauri while the journey was underway.

@reiterwriter Most of an introductory special relativity course can be done with nothing but algebra, and little will be lost if you use a computer to help you with the calculus and trigonometry. If you're interested in writing realistic sci-fi involving relativistic astronauts - or just learning about the intricate beauty of the way the universe works - I'd recommend working through a textbook or a course on the subject.

MIT has a free online course with lectures and sample questions (you'll still need to buy the textbooks or get them with interlibrary loan) here. Einstein's textbook for educated but non-expert general audiences is in the public domain here (you only need Part 1, the Special Theory).

@Escapeddentalpatient. I remember a documentary on the MiG in which the Russians claimed to have pilots who could operate at 12g, in g suits, "during combat maneuvers" which was not a sustained journey by any means.

Amazing if accurate. There's not much margin for overdoing the counter-pressure and giving the pilot a hemorrhagic stroke. @Ash

I am not sure if I follow other answers. Let's ignore time dilation before we hit the desired travel speed for simplicity.
At 3g acceleration and deceleration we can reach the speed of light in 4 months. We would also travel for 2 light months of distance during that time. We also need to decelerate to 0 which will take another 4 months and will cover 2 light months. We are left with ~46 months to cover at close to speed of light so that it would take a month for the travelers. This roughly translates to 0.999765c. So in total, roughly 4.5 years.
You could decrease that to 2.6g if you are willing to hit almost 1c. But I am guessing it would be much more difficult to do that.

This is a great answer.

If you boost at 3g (ship frame proper acceleration) for 4 months (Earth frame) you end up at about 0.7c and the journey takes about 3 years. If you boost at 3g (Earth frame coordinate acceleration) for 4 months, you flatten yourself with hundreds of gravities of proper acceleration along the way.

If you want to read up, you're looking for the difference between velocity and rapidity.

So I shouldn't ignore relativity, but since this is not even science based, I am guessing this answer could be used to cheat it.

I appreciate you considering the accel and decel aspects, but just so I'm clear, are you saying it's 4.5 years to the Earth observer, or a 4.5 year journey for the travelers? I'm employing handwavium and cryo tech for the squishy humans, so I'm less interested in the mechanics of the trip, as I am in the time consequences (MC is leaving family behind).

@reiterwriter 4.5 for Earth observer. 9 months for those in the ship.

Assuming you have inertial dampeners or functional equivalent, so that we don't need to worry about squishing the squishy humans as in g s's answer, there's an easy way to do the calculation. It looks like Pythagoras' theorem but with a minus sign instead of a plus sign:
$$
(\text{ship time})^2 = (\text{Earth time})^2 - (\text{distance})^2.
$$
You have to measure time in years and distance in lightyears (or time in seconds and distance in light-seconds etc.) for it to work.
In your case you want the ship time to be 9 months = 0.75 years and the distance is 4.2 light-years, so
$$
(0.75)^2 = (\text{Earth time})^2 - (4.2)^2
$$
or
$$
\text{Earth time} = \sqrt{(0.75)^2+(4.2)^2} \approx 4.27\,\text{years}. 
$$
This is assuming flat space-time (a reasonable approximation in this case) and travel at a constant speed (may or may not be reasonable depending on the properties of handwavium).

I think this answer could be improved by using (s/c)^2 instead of s^2 so you don't need c=yr=1 units.

@gs I suppose that's a matter of taste - I was going for making it as easy to understand as possible and I don't think the choice makes it any less correct (it arguably makes it more correct). OP is using light-years and years anyway.

No one's fault but my own, as I don't grasp "why" it's true, but it looks like the time that passes on Earth would still equate to around 4.2 light years for observers watching our 9-month handwavium travellers. That is very interesting, and could add some complexity to my intended plot. Thank you for this simple answer that accounts for my handwavium =)
